# Using VBA to insert/update image in PowerPoint?

Tags: image, vba, powerpoint

I am making an interactive Powerpoint presentation that has previously read a text file from my local server (XAMPP) and displayed it.  I'd like to now update it so that the user can hand-write their response, and it displays that on the slideshow.  I have a jQuery plugin that lets someone use a stylus and it saves the 'drawing' as an image on the local server.

My question is, how can I insert the image into PowerPoint using a VBA Macro?  Or since the image always will have the same file path, but will be replaced with a different image, can I somehow "Update" the image on the slide?  Sorry if it's confusing.

This is the VBA I tried:

```
Sub insert()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("http://localhost/image.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

I could also get the path of the image on the computer, not the server.

When I run the macro, I get a "file not found" error.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks!

PS: If anyone's interested, the plugin is called [Signature Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I can insert an image if it's in the exact same folder:

```
Sub insert()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("image.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

This works, but if anyone knows how to go into another folder, please let me know. If I try `folder/image.png` or `/folder/image.png` as the file path, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your first code because when I run it for any picture in the web it is than placed in my presentation. For pictures on your computer you should rather state full path or set 'current directory' by changing it to one of your choice using `ChDir c:\my path\here`

Comment: @KazJaw Perhaps it's different on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be in the exact same folder, but you do need to use Mac-style paths:

```
#If Mac Then
    imagePath = (MacScript("get path to startup disk as string") & "Users:name:Desktop:SomeFolder:My_Picture.png")
#Else
    imagePath = "C:\path\to\My_Picture.png"
#End If

activeSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath, False, True, 10, 10)
```

Hope that helps.